# How to deallocate memory?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, garbage-collection, enumerable

I have the following method for looping through a table, changint some values in every row and saving the chages back to the database. To make things go faster I am fetching data in sets of 10,000 rows. This is a large table with over 25 million records in it.

The problem is that my application doesn't seems to be releasing any memory. I have tried redeclaring the `records` variable to `nothing` or explicitly caling the garbage collector but the memory stays there. 
Runnning the built-in VS10 profiler I can see that the culprit is the `system.linq.enumerable.tolist()` method which takes up over 98% of my memory. How do I release that memory after the call to `saveChanges`?

```
db = New databaseEntities
Dim size = 25000000
Dim stepSize = 10000
For i = 0 to size Step stepSize
  Dim sql = (From A In db.table).OrderBy(Function(A) A.Column).Skip(i).Take(stepSize)
  Dim records As New List(Of table)
  records = sql.ToList
  For Each record In records
    'do some work
  Next
  db.SaveChanges()
  records = Nothing
  GC.Collect()
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repository holds a reference to each entity it is tracking, so you won't be able to dispose an entity whilst the repository is live and tracking it. That means you either need to dispose the repository, or detach each entity after you've finished processing it.

Option 1) if "do some work" doesn't affect the order you'd return records in, you could move the creation of databaseEntities inside the For loop, and declare it with a using block. That should cause each block of entities to be release each time round the for loop

Option 2) If your operation is essentially parallel, and what you do to one "table" entity doesn't  have any dependencies on any other, then you could call databaseEntities.Detach(record) after db.SaveChanges, which will enable the garbage collector to reclaim the entity's space.

Looking at your code, I suspect either of thse could be used

Comment: Option 2 is very slow. Takes around a minute to detach 10,000 records (in comparison updating them takes around 2 seconds). So I guess I'm gonna go with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this: (I didn't test it)

```
db.SaveChanges()
For Each record In records
    record.dispose ''only if class table got a dispose method
Next
records.clear
records = Nothing
```

Comment: No, there are not dispose properties in the table object.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means a Linq to SQL expert, but my guess is that the DataContext caches all rows you have read so you must either empty the cache or lose you reference to the DataContext.

Comment: I think you have something here. If I declare a new instacne of db inside the `for` loop the memory issue goes away. However, I don't think that is a very good solution. There should be some way of telling the entity manager to clear the cache.

Comment: It's not about the memory manager then, it's about the DataContext. You have to tell the DataContext to clear its cache, and the memory manager will reclaim the memory whenever it wants to.

Comment: @Pavel, doing actions on large number of records is a bit of a weakness of EF. If I was doing the same action across a large number of entities, and performance was a priority, I'd probably use a stored procedure instead. It does mean some of your business logic is now in the database instead of the model, but sometimes we have to be pragmatic about these things.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to *update* the entities, use `MergeOption.NoTracking`. The context will no longer keep a reference to the entity, nor will it do fixup.

Comment: True, though the fact he loads table entities (and apparently nothing else), does some work, then calls db.SaveChanges tends to imply that he does need to track changes.